# How to serialize object with the same complex prop types, but different names

Tags: c#, json

I have the next models

```
public class Record
{
    public User User{ get; set; }

    public User Sister { get; set; }

    public User Mother { get; set; }

    ...
}

public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

The target json, after serializing should look like the following

```
{
   "user":{
      "user_name":"UserName",
      "user_id":"id"
   },
   "sister":{
      "sister1_name":"UserName",
      "sister1_id":"id"
   },
   "mother":{
      "mother_name":"UserName",
      "mother_id":"id"
   }
}
```

The problem is that all these fields have the same type, but I need different names for every property. So using attributes isn't an option here. I tried to play with `CustomContractResolver`, but didn't get too far. It would be nice to have a possibility to set name resolver on property name, but as far as I know it's impossible. Do we have another way to do it clean and extensible? 
P.S. I'm using Newtonsoft Json, but I consider other options if any

Comment: How are you implementing the serialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Creating dynamic Objects**

You can do something with a method that creates a new JSON object and append it to a parent object.

```
public static void CreateUser (JObject parent, string type, string Name, string Id)
{
    parent[type] = new JObject
    {
        [$"{type}_name"] = Name,
        [$"{type}_id"] = Id
    };

}
```

and in the main, use the following code to create and write to console the json object.

```
var parent = new JObject();
CreateUser(parent, "user", "UserName", "UserID");
CreateUser(parent, "sister", "SisterName", "SisterID");
CreateUser(parent, "mother", "MotherName", "MotherID");
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parent, Formatting.Indented));
```

This is what the json object would like,

```
{
  "user": {
    "user_name": "UserName",
    "user_id": "UserID"
  },
  "sister": {
    "sister_name": "SisterName",
    "sister_id": "SisterID"
  },
  "mother": {
    "mother_name": "MotherName",
    "mother_id": "MotherID"
  }
}
```

---

**Creating Array of objects**

Above example shows you how to create objects, below shows how you can create an array of sisters or mothers.

```
public static void AddUser (JObject parent, string type, string Name, string Id)
{
    JArray arr = (JArray)parent[type] ?? new JArray();
    arr.Add(new JObject
    {
        [$"{type}{arr.Count() + 1}_name"] = Name,
        [$"{type}{arr.Count() + 1}_id"] = Id
    });
    parent[type] = arr;
}
```

and you will use the above like,

```
var parent = new JObject();
CreateUser(parent, "user", "UserName", "UserID");
CreateUser(parent, "mother", "MotherName", "MotherID");
AddUser(parent, "sister", "SisterName", "SisterID");
AddUser(parent, "sister", "SisterName2", "SisterID2");

Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parent, Formatting.Indented));
```

and the result will be,

```
{
  "user": {
    "user_name": "UserName",
    "user_id": "UserID"
  },
  "mother": {
    "mother_name": "MotherName",
    "mother_id": "MotherID"
  },
  "sister": [
    {
      "sister1_name": "SisterName",
      "sister1_id": "SisterID"
    },
    {
      "sister2_name": "SisterName2",
      "sister2_id": "SisterID2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It's not gonna work for "sister". Because, we have `sister1_name` instead of `sister_name`. But definitely we can create for sister another method.

Comment: @managerger see my update with "how to create array of objects". I am sure you can clean up the method but just as an idea, wanted to show how you can use JObjects and JArrays to create dynamic jsons.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be something like this:

We could make your customer class abstract and create one class for each type of customer (User/Sister/Mother)

```
public class Record
{
    public User User { get; set; }

    public Sister Sister { get; set; }

    public Mother Mother { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

[JsonPrefix(Prefix = "User")]
public class User : Customer { }
[JsonPrefix(Prefix = "Sister1")]
public class Sister : Customer { }
[JsonPrefix(Prefix = "Mother")]
public class Mother : Customer { }
```

Now we create that JsonPrefix attribute and a custom serializer for it so the resulting json has the prefix.

```
public class JsonPrefix : Attribute
{
    public string Prefix { get; set; }
}

public class CustomResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{

    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var ret = new List<JsonProperty>();
        foreach (var prop in base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization))
        {
            var cst = type.GetCustomAttribute<JsonPrefix>();
            if (cst != null)
                prop.PropertyName = $"{cst.Prefix}_{prop.PropertyName}";

            ret.Add(prop);
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

And in the end you call like this:

```
        var data1 = new Record();
        data1.User = new User() { Name = "Test" };
        data1.Sister = new Sister() { Name = "Test2" };
        data1.Mother = new Mother() { Name = "Test3" };

        JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new CustomResolver(),
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented
        };

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data1, settings);
```

The resulting Json will be like you need it. The only drawback is the need to make a new class inheriting from the customer class for new type of data in the json.